# Django not loading static files (Pycharm)

Tags: python, css, django, pycharm

I am working on a project which requires loading on a CSS stylesheet and a logo file. But my Django server also returns 404 resource not found while loading these files. I have checked other questions like this but none of them is using the format to specify static files I used.
This is the html code i am using

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/Emu86/style.css">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

This is my settings.py file:

```
    """
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.9.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/deployment/checklist/



# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'Emu86',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_extensions',

]

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] \
                %(message)s",
                'datefmt': "%d%b%Y %H:%M:%S"
         },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'file': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'Emu86.log',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'propagate': True,
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
        'Emu86': {
            'handlers': ['file'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    },
}
```

Project Structure:

```
Emu86/
  mysite/
      static/ 
        Emu86/
```

Comment: You shoul show the folder structure of your app, chiefly of your static folder

Comment: in your settings file says is django 1.9.1

Comment: Does that make a difference? I am running it using Pycharm

Comment: Your folder structure is strange: is `mysite` the project folder or the app folder?

Comment: It is app folder, how can I identify it ? It has settings.py

Comment: if it has settings.py then is the project folder

Comment: Emu86 is app and mysite is project folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to do some changes in **setting.py**

Add

`STATICFILES_DIRS = [
     os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]`

below **BASE_DIR....**

hope it works

Comment: Of all the methods this worked well, Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
{% load static %}    
{% block stylesheets %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "Emu86/style.css"%}">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

I guess the path has to be as above

Comment: This gives an Error:  Invalid block tag on line 10: 'static', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: oops, I thought you were importing the static template, but I added an edit that might be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the [`static`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) template tag at the top of your template and then use it for getting the url to your static files:

```
{% load static %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "Emu86/style.css" %}">
{% endblock stylesheets %}
```

**edit**

You have to define in your **settings.py** file the `STATICFILES_DIRS` constant to look for your static folder from the project directory:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "mysite", "static"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all add this  `'django.template.context_processors.static'` to your context_processors array. And then in your template file use static file like this
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{STATIC_URL}}Emu86/style.css">`

** Do not forget to place all your static file in your static folder.